# Pointing many domains to cloudfront sub directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a single page application which is hosted on s3 and have cloudfront pointing to it. The app is multi-tenant, so the "tenants" need to be able to point their domain to a subdirectory.

Example: `sometenant.com` should point to `app.domain.com/sometenant`

**Is this possible?** Fairly hard to test with deployment/propagation/etc...

Also wondering if I could keep pushstate working, if it's possible that is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but not with a single CloudFront distribution -- a single CloudFront distribution can accept and handle requests for multiple subdomains, but unless the origin web server behind CloudFront can vary the response based on the hostname (and this won't work with S3 as the origin server), the basic assumption is that all of the domains pointing to a distribution result in the same behavior.

You'll need a CloudFront distribution for each domain.  Not a problem, because the [default limit of 200](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_cloudfront) distributions per account can be increased on request... and distributions are easily created in automation... and you don't pay a fee for each distribution -- just the bandwidth and requests, which will essentially the same.

Each CloudFront distribution can then be configured with a [default root object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDefaultRootObject) -- this is the page fetched from the back-end when the root `/` page is requested. Set this to `sometenant` and, for this distribution, the root page will be requested from the bucket as `GET /sometenant`. Any other page/object request (images, css, etc.) is forwarded straight through to the bucket.

Each tenant site needs its domain added as an alternate name for its distribution, then you configure the tenant's site to point to the distribution's assigned dxxxexample.cloudfront.net endpoint, in DNS.